# Matplotlib segmentation fault Mac OS 11(Big Sur)

Tags: matplotlib, macos-big-sur

I am using the matplotlib's backend MacOSX to show a plot on GUI with the newest Mac OS 11 big sur.

The script fails with a segmentation fault. Any ideas or solutions, why this might be ?

The backend TKAgg works though but since its deprecated, I would like a solution with the backend  MacOSX..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and was using matplotlib 3.1.0. Upgrading to matplotlib 3.3.3 fixed the issue : pip install --upgrade matplotlib